# MiniDLNA performance issue

Tags: media-server

I've set up my Pi with `minidlna`. My `PS3` sees it and I can play media files of most sort. There are a few minor performance issues though. Playing video is sometimes a bit choppy (which I can live with), but what really bothers me is that it can take 10 seconds or more to start playing a mp3. So browsing through music becomes very annoying and almost impossible.

I have a `WD Passport` USB powered external HDD hooked up to the Pi with the media files on it. I can transfer data at up to 30MB/s so I don't think the drive itself is the issue.

Is this a common issue? Has anyone had similar experiences?

Comment: I have a very similar setup, and I experience the same types of performance issues. Overclocking the Pi does not seem to have any effect. I am using a wireless connection with my PS3, however. From my experience overall, the PS3 wireless performance is terrible. Is your PS3 wired or wireless? My next step is to try a wired connection.

Comment: If the minidlna does not support hardware encodding then it will be choppy because it uses CPU. This is for transcodding but maybe try h264/mp4 video and see it that helps.

Comment: Using a wired connection fixed this for me. Although theoretically a wireless connection should be sufficient to play media fast and smooth, I'm guessing there is too much overhead?